# Namespace the real meaning

Tags: php, namespaces

I have read about namespaces and I played a bit with them just now. But I want to make sure that I got this right.

1) So namespaces are here to save as from duplications of name, really good when you add sources from outside into an application for example

2) Is it a good practice to use namespaces, to avoid duplication

3) Is it a good practice to use a namespace like a folder structure, For example if I have Folder/Folder1/Fileone.php to call my namespace like this: namespace Zend/Folder1/Fileone;

I just wanted to make sure that I got this right, and namespaces are basically here to keep as organized and is good to use them know.

Comment: I recommend playing with Python for a bit in order to gain a strong understanding of namespaces.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Playing with python makes no sense here. At Uffo, yes, your assumptions are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Exactly, namespaces make sure there's no conflict between two libraries/code bases/projects which declare the same classes. It's even useful within one application to separate different classes which may logically be given the same name; say `View\User` and `Model\User`.

   You can get the same benefit by naming your classes `class View_User` etc., but this means you *always* have to use the class by that name. Look at some larger projects like Zend Framework 1.0 to see what a verbose mess this leads to. With namespaces you can use shorter names within the same namespace and alias classes to short names easily.
2. Yes, it's best to namespace all your code with `ProjectName\...` or even `VendorName\ProjectName\...` to make sure you're avoiding collisions with 3rd party code.
3. Yes, if you correlate folder names to class names (including namespaces), it's easy to use an autoloader. It also simply makes sense.

Comment: "....With namespaces you can use shorter names within the same namespace and alias classes to short names easily." you mean for example Zend\Model\Abstract\Inherit to do something like: use Zend\Model\Abstract\Inherit as Zend\M\I ?

Comment: Yes, although `... as Zend\M\I` happens to not work. You can do something like `... as IModel` though.

Comment: @deceze While he can name a stuff like `IModel`, that is simply wrong. There are no Models in `MVC`, but `Services`

Comment: @Dave That's not the point here. Yes, I know what "the model" in MVC is. No, this not the point to get into a discussion about it.